# How to install mac os apps with script?

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I live in a country which almost no buty use Mac, so I grew up in IT without any knowledge regarding Mac OS.

At the moment I am working in a company which have lots of people who uses Mac PC's, because of the Covid-19 situation, most of them working from home and we are implementing Checkpoint and Fortigate in few of our branches around the country, I was able to make a Batch script to install a costume Forticlient with all the configuration inside it, the script first importing the registry then installing the app itself, after that copying the RDP file to the desktop of the user, all this was packed into Self extracted zip file, and everything is installed in silent mode.

How can I achieve the same in Mac OS?, I was able to download the Microsoft Rdp package and the checkpoint and fortigate packages (there is .pkg and .dmg file).

I have a Catalina and Mojave VM to do the tests.

I've searched the web and found out that Apple has some simple scripting language which called "Apple script", does this language can accomplish this task? or I should look for another solution?

Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: On macOS AppleScript is state-of-the-art regarding automation.

Comment: can it be use to install apps "silently" ?

Comment: Basically yes but it depends.

Comment: Hi,
It depends on what?

Comment: Your question is quite vague. It depends on the concrete workflow.

Comment: ok, as I write the question, how can i export package from zip and install it without the intervention of the user?

Comment: Sorry, this is an ambiguous information, too. As far as the base installation location is in the home folder of the user no interaction is required, if components are supposed to be installed in folders which are owned by the OS you have to enter the admin password. But this is quite normal in macOS.

Comment: I don't think that this question is so hard, it's very simple, how to do you install software automatically on MacOS?